# Proving a continous function

Tags: functions, continuity

How can i prove the function

f : **R** $\xrightarrow {}$ **R**

x $\mapsto {}$ -2 |x|

is continuous at every point?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Simply divide it into $2$ functions.  For $x < 0, f(x) = -2(-x) = 2x.$  For $x > 0, f(x) = -2x.$  It is then immediate that at every point except for $x = 0$, that $f(x)$ is a continuous function.  So, use $\epsilon,\delta$ to prove that $f(x) = -2|x|$ is also continuous at $x = 0$.

Comment: Show that $|f(x)-f(y)| \le 2|x-y|.$

Answer (score 1):

For any $x\in\mathbb R,\,\epsilon>0$, we have $\bigl|-2|x|-(-2|y|)\bigr|=2\bigl||x|-|y|\bigr|\le2|x-y|<\epsilon$ for all $y\in B_\epsilon(x)$.
Hence the function $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R,\,x\mapsto-2|x|$ is continuous.
Note that we used the triangle inequality $\bigl||x|-|y|\bigr|\le|x-y|.$